# Kendo ui logarithmic line chart, chart is not show if all values are 1

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I show line chart with log type, it working fine if one of the value is greater then 1, But when all the values are set 1 the chart is never show. Also if I set the max: 5 in valueaxis then it working but the values are variable it may be greater then 5 so I can't set it with 5.

Comment: Please post your code and I can help.

Comment: Please check on http://dojo.telerik.com/UZaBo/2

Comment: Code updated to dynamically set a max value when you click refresh ... does that help your situation? http://dojo.telerik.com/UZaBo/3

Comment: Thank you, But how to identify that my all values are 1

Comment: can you give me idea to how to get the max value. So I will set the max with 10 if max value is 1 otherwise it work normally without set the max.

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/UZaBo/3 updated with comments to dynamically set the max value based on the max value found in your data array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this - improved version of the comment above.

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, internetUsers.map(
  function(data) 
  { 
    return data.firstName_measure; 
  }));

chart.options.valueAxis.max = max + 2;
chart.refresh();
```